# How do I access to a widget that is in a QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, tabwidget

I think it's easy but i stuck...
I've got a QTabwidget and inserted a new tab with insertTab.

```
tabwidget.insertTab(idx, new QWebView, "uninterestingTitle");
```

Now I would like to access the containing QWebView (or in general any widget, that i put into my tab), for modify... but how?
I know how to access any tab (currentIndex, currentWidget,...), but im not sure how to access a containing widget (like above my QWebView).

Does currentWidget return my QWebView?

Sry, but i'm confused and thankful for any advice. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by inserting a new tab the tab/page itself is your QWebView i.e. `tabwidget.widget(idx)` is your QWebView. Thats what I understand from Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtabwidget.html#insertTab); (let me know if am wrong)

*If the QTabWidget was empty before this function is called, the new page becomes the current page. Inserting a new tab at an index less than or equal to the current index will increment the current index, but keep the current page.*

Comment: well it works... i only had to convert the output... because widget(idx) returns a widget... so following workes fine:(QWebView*) tabWidget->widget(idx); PS: thx :D